# implementing stack in C with generic style

Tags: c, generics

file stack.h

```
typedef struct
{
    void *elems;
    int elem_size;
    int log_len;
    int alloc_len;
    void (*free_fn)(void *);
} stack;

void stack_new(stack *s, int elem_size, void (*free_fn)(void *));
void stack_dispose(stack *s);
void stack_push(stack *s, void *value);
void stack_pop(stack *s, void *address);
```

and the implementation file stack.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define assert(condition) if(!condition) printf("assert fail\n");exit(0) 

void strfree(void *elem);

int main()
{
    stack s;
    int i;
    char *copy, *top;
    const char *friends[] = {"joe", "castiel", "lily"};
    stack_new(&s, sizeof(char *), strfree);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        copy = strdup(friends[i]);
        stack_push(&s, &cp);
    }

    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        stack_pop(&s, &top);
        printf("%s\n", top);
    }
    stack_dispose(&s);
    return 1;
}

void strfree(void *elem)
{
    free(*(char **)elem);
}

void stack_new(stack *s, int elem_size, void (*free_fn)(void *))
{
    assert(elem_size > 0);
    s->alloc_len = 4;
    s->free_fn = free_fn;
    s->log_len = 0;
    s->elem_size = elem_size;
    s->elems = malloc(s->alloc_len * s->elem_size);
    assert(s->elems != NULL);
}

void stack_dispose(stack *s)
{
    int i;
    if(s->free_fn)
    {
        for(i=0; i<s->log_len; i++)
        {
            s->free_fn((char *)s->elems + i * s->elem_size);
        }
    }
    free(s->elems);
}

void stack_push(stack *s, void *v)
{
    if(s->log_len == s->alloc_len)
    {
        s->alloc_len *= 2;
        s->elems = realloc(s->elems, s->alloc_len*s->elem_size);
        assert(s->elems != NULL);
    }
    memcpy((char *)s->elems+s->log_len*s->elem_size, v, s->elem_size);
    s->log_len++;
}

void stack_pop(stack *s, void *address)
{
    assert(s->log_len > 0);
    void *source =  (char *)s->elems + (s->log_len - 1) * s->elem_size;
    memcpy(address, source, s->elem_size);
    s->log_len--;
}
```

So it compiles but it doesn't run.

1. It has a warning about comparison between pointer and integer which comes from the code

   ```
   assert(s->elems != NULL);
   ```
2. It is broken somewhere, it will not print out the three names defined here

   ```
   const char *friends[] = {"joe", "castiel", "lily"};
   ```

I know the code is bit of too much, but I really wish to get some help, I'm at my wits end here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is your `assert` macro:

```
#define assert(condition) if(!condition) printf("assert fail\n");exit(0)
```

The `exit(0);` is executed regardless of whether the condition is true or false (look at the generated code again).  If you want assertions, use the standard `#include <assert.h>`.

Your first identified problem is with:

```
assert(s->elems != NULL);
```

Given the definition, this is equivalent to:

```
if (!s->elems != NULL)
    printf("assert fail\n");
exit(0);
```

The `!s->elems` is an integer, either 0 or 1, compared with a null pointer constant.  Hence the warning.  When writing macros, enclose arguments in parentheses.  At minimum:

```
#define assert(condition) if(!(condition)){printf("assert fail\n");exit(1);}
```

This still isn't a good macro, but at least it will get rid of the first compilation error, and your `stack_new()` won't exit when it is called just because it is called.  Note that it is conventional to exit with a non-zero status when there is a problem — exiting with zero indicates success.

Answer (score 1):

Run your code in a debugger using GDB to see what it is doing line by line.  Google "gdb cheat sheet" to get started and compile your code with `-g`.

Comment: thank u, because I'm not using IDE, I forgot that I can debug my code